# Pass datagrid.ItemsSource as a generic list in a generic function

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I am tryting to implement paggination on datagrid, which can contain different types of lists e.g. `Teacher, Student` etc
How can I call the button click event so that my Paginate function can filter that list and set the itemssource of my datagrid

```
    public List<T> Paginate<T>(List<T> list, int itemsPerPage, int currentPage)
    {
        // some code
    }


    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        this.Paginate(myDataGrid.ItemsSource,3,1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have no restrictions to the elements and access it only by index and don't use extra filtering by object properties then you can use non-generic types in your code:

```
public IList Paginate(IList list, int itemsPerPage, int currentPage)
{
    // some code
}

private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    this.Paginate(myDataGrid.ItemsSource as IList, 3, 1);
}
```

But you should do it only if you are ensure that [`ItemsSource`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource(v=vs.110).aspx) contains an object that implements `IList`, for example, `List<T>`. If you are not sure you will need to use `IEnumerable` interface and iterate collection for each paging.

Answer (score 0):

try this , for this solution you need to atlest provide information which datalist is binded

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   if(boundlist=="Employee")
   {
    List<Employee> copy = new List<Employee>
    ((myDataGrid.ItemsSource as IList).OfType<Employee>());
    this.Paginate<Employee>(copy,3,1);
   }
   else if(boundlist=="Student")
   {
    List<Student> copy = new List<Employee>
    ((myDataGrid.ItemsSource as IList).OfType<Student>());
    this.Paginate<Student>(copy,3,1);
   }
}
```

Comment: @M.Arslan - yes that's true but I guess for converting things you must need to write down this...

Answer (score 0):

If Paginate is just for paging then just pass it as a list of objects.

```
private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{            
    this.Paginate(myDataGrid.ItemsSource as IList<object>, 3, 1);
}
```